# How to sort files with a certain permission by size?

Tags: command-line, permissions, sort

I need to sort all my files with 644 permissions by size.

So far I've tried using the `ls` command to find and sort but they don't seem right. I think it may need a `grep` command but I think it needs to show numbers like 644 not rwx. I don't know how to do that in a simple way since its my first time using Linux and the terminal in general.

Comment: This sounds like homework. Could you elaborate on what you mean with "they don't seem right"? Are you missing files? Is it an incomplete solution? Sharing what you've already done might allow someone to offer a suggestion on how to reach your goal 

Comment: Read `man find stat`.

Answer (score 10):

In your standard `bash` shell, you can do that with the find command:

```
find . -perm 0644 -printf '%s %p\n'| sort -nr
```

This finds all files and directories with permissions `0644` and prints the results formatted using the `-printf` action. `%s` represents the file size and `%p` the file path. `\n` represents a new line. The output is piped into `sort`, set to sort numerically (`-n`) and in reverse order (`-r`).

Comment: thank you so much for the help

Answer (score 6):

Using the Z shell (`zsh`) with its *glob qualifiers*:

```
print -rC1 *(.DNf:u=6,go=4:oL)
```

where the meanings are

- . matches plain files only
- D sets the GLOB_DOTS option for the current pattern
- N sets the NULL_GLOB option for the current pattern
- f*spec* matches files with access rights matching *spec*
- oL orders the results by length (size in bytes); use OL to reverse the order

Comment: You gave them the answer to the bonus question! LOL

Comment: @stumblebee irl I would probably have used `find` with `-perm` and `-printf` to output size and name, then sort and cut the result - I was just interested in exploring how to do it in zsh!

Comment: This is a brilliant answer on several levels. Most entertaining answer I've seen today!

Comment: thank you so much for the answer

Comment: the deadline was like two days ago so no worries no bonus points for this, just wanted to learn how to do that :D im not taking credit for other peoples work